# More Scala typing issues

Tags: scala, types

Now that Kim Stebel [helped me understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126076/supertype-for-scalaquery-query) how to type variables with existential types, i need to know how to use them in inheritance:

the following code doesn’t compile:

```
class PagingListModel(startPageNumber: Int, pageSize: Int, query: Query[Projection[_ <: Product]]) extends AbstractListModel {
    val itemStartNumber: Int = startPageNumber * pageSize
    val items: List[Product] = getPageData()

    override def getPageData(): List[Product] = {
        db withSession {
            return queryToQueryInvoker(query.drop(itemStartNumber).take(pageSize)).list
        }
    }
}
```

…with the error:

```
no type parameters for method queryToQueryInvoker:
(q: org.scalaquery.ql.Query[org.scalaquery.ql.ColumnBase[T]])
org.scalaquery.ql.basic.BasicQueryInvoker[T]
exist so that it can be applied to arguments
(org.scalaquery.ql.Query[org.scalaquery.ql.Projection[_ <: Product]])
--- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
found :   org.scalaquery.ql.Query[org.scalaquery.ql.Projection[_ <: Product]]
required: org.scalaquery.ql.Query[org.scalaquery.ql.ColumnBase[?T]]
```

…which is strange, because the required type is really inside the bounds of the found one…

PS: i really only want to be able to call `foreach` on each Tuple in the list returned by `getPageData()`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with an existential type. It works with a type parameter:

```
class PagingListModel[T <: Product](... query: Query[Projection[T]]) {
  ...
  def getPageData(): List[_ <: Product] = ...
    queryToQueryInvoker(query.drop(itemStartNumber).take(pageSize)).list
}
```

The original version would be correct but Scala cannot typecheck it due to a limitation similar to Haskell's monomorphism restriction. The type parameter for queryToQueryInvoker would have to be a universal type `[T <: Product] forAll { type T }` which is not supported by Scala.

By using an explicit type parameter, queryToQueryInvoker can be instantiated with that specific type. The method can still return `List[_ <: Product]` because List is co-variant in its element type.

**Edit:** It is possible after all. You have to move the existential to the right place:

```
class PagingListModel(... query: Query[Projection[T]] forSome { type T <: Product })  {
  def getPageData(): List[_ <: Product] = ... {
    val i = queryToQueryInvoker(query.drop(itemStartNumber).take(pageSize))
    i.list
  }
}
```

Without the extra variable `i` the compiler will infer the wrong type and then complain about it. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: looks good! that certainly is one thing i never thought of the whole damn time i tried to find my mistake…

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge of ScalaQuery is limited, but it looks as though you should be parameterizing the class.

```
class PagingListModel[T <: Product] (
  startPageNumber: Int,
  pageSize: Int,
  query: Query[Projection[T]]
) extends AbstractListModel {
  ...
}
```

Existentials can be tricky, and are best avoided if at all possible.

Comment: i have thought of that, but when cunstructing a query, how to use it’s type in as type parameter then?

Comment: You shouldn't need to be explicit with the type param. The compiler will determine it for you based on the type of the `Projection` you supply as an argument.