# Compile error using flatMap with Sets and type bounds

Tags: scala

Consider the following, which compiles:

```
  val f: String => Set[Integer] = ???
  val a: Set[String] = ???
  val b = a.flatMap(s => f(s))
```

Now, if I change the first line above as following, the code no longer compiles:

```
  val f: String => Set[_ <: Integer] = ???
  val a: Set[String] = ???
  val b = a.flatMap(s => f(s))
```

The error is the following:

```
/Foo.scala:31: error: no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: String => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String],B,That])That exist so that it can be applied to arguments (String => scala.collection.immutable.Set[_ <: Integer])
[ERROR]  --- because ---
[ERROR] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
[ERROR]  found   : String => scala.collection.immutable.Set[_ <: Integer]
[ERROR]  required: String => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?B]
[ERROR]   val b = a.flatMap(s => f(s))
[ERROR]             ^
[ERROR] /Foo.scala:31: error: type mismatch;
[ERROR]  found   : String => scala.collection.immutable.Set[_ <: Integer]
[ERROR]  required: String => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]
[ERROR]   val b = a.flatMap(s => f(s))
[ERROR]                       ^
[ERROR] /Foo.scala:31: error: Cannot construct a collection of type That with elements of type B based on a collection of type scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]. 
[ERROR]   val b = a.flatMap(s => f(s))
```

Why does a compile error result here (I don't understand the above compiler error message), and how should I fix it?

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141701/more-scala-typing-issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means that Scala doesn't know what type you mean. Let's write something that works:

```
val b = a.flatMap[Integer, Set[Integer]](s => f(s))
```

There are two type parameters to `flatMap`. The second parameter is the final type you'll get. That is, `b`, above, will be of type `Set[Integer]`. It could well be declared as `Set[_ <: Integer]`, but that might be confused with the declaration of `f`, so I decided to make it different in that example.

The *first* parameter is the type of elements that will go into that collection (that is, the elements that will be produced by `s => f(s)`). So let's go back to `f`:

```
val f: String => Set[_ <: Integer] = ???
```

The type of element produced is an unknown subtype of `Integer` -- and, being unknown, Scala can't figure out what to use. Or, in order words, it can't *infer* the type parameters for `flatMap`.

By the way, if you want to keep `Set[_ <: Integer]` all the way, you could do this:

```
val b = a.flatMap[Integer, Set[_ <: Integer]](s => f(s))
```

Or even, to obfuscate everything,

```
val b = a.flatMap[T forSome { type T <: Integer }, Set[_ <: Integer]](s => f(s))
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but why does `flatMap` take two type parameters here, even though the docs only specify one? The signature of `flatMap` for `Set` appears to be `def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): Set[B]`

Comment: @jonderry That's the "use case" signature: a fake type signature which is easier to read and explains what happens most of the time, but isn't actually real. If you expand the doc for `flatMap`, you'll see a "Full Signature" session that can also be expanded to show the full type signature of the method.